# ExecuteTransactionRequest run-time limitations

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I know that `ExecuteMultipleRequest` have some run-time limitations, max `batchSize` of 1000 and some others ([as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

But I'm interested in `ExecuteTransactionRequest` and didn't find anything in documentation.

Does this operation have same limitations? If so, how can I execute more then 1000 requests?

**For example:**

- Have 3000 requests in collection.
- Split them in 3 batches (each 1000).
- Successful execute first two batches, but third batch fail.
- **Because third batch failed, I also want to restore first and second batch.**

Is this possible?

I am using CRM 2015.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2015/04/19/New-CRM-SDK-Feature---Transactional-Batching